# Error when subclassing QTextEdit using PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to subclass QTextEdit and override the mouseMoveEvent. I am getting the error "TypeError: PySide.QtGui.QAbstractScrollArea isn't a direct base class of QTextEdit2". What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the scroll area be inherited?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class QTextEdit2(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QTextEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print("mouseMoveEvent: x=%d, y=%d" % (event.x(), event.y()))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QTextEdit2()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Change `super(QTextEdit, self).__init__(parent)` to `super(QTextEdit2, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you can simply do `super().__init__(parent)`, which nicely avoids having to repeat the class name. Also, it may be advisable to add `super().mouseMoveEvent(event)` to the end of your overridden method so you don't lose the default behaviour (assuming there is any).

Comment: @eyllanesc, it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: @ekhumoro, I am indeed using Python 3. Thanks for the tip about the super() mouse event.